# I want regex for int<any no of spaces>,<any no of spaces>int<any no of spaces>,<any no of spaces>int

Tags: regex

and there are exactly 3 integers. No floats allowed. No characters allowed. Just integers.

Comment: `(\d+)[,](\d+)[,](\d+)`

Comment: This would match more then the precise number of ints required.

Comment: good catch, I think, int is nearly 65k, so, we must use {4-5}

Comment: @loldop: On what basis are you assuming an integer is 16 bits and unsigned?

Comment: 4 bytes. I think, that it is normal int from C

Comment: @loldop: C only requires `int` to be at least 16 bits, and a byte to be at least 8 bits. But the OP said nothing either about C or about restricting the range of the integers. If you want to restrict the range of an integer, you can write an ugly regex to do it, but a regex really isn't the right tool for that job.

Comment: Regex is about strings. it has no idea what an integer is. btw. in which notation the integer as string? As ascii characters? as byte-sequences as unicode codepoints 32bit? As binary? As Octal? As Hex? As Dec? So what now? - Did you mean digits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern for that is this: `\d+\s*,\s*\d+\s*,\s*\d+`

Matches three digits with any number of spaces

Comment: Actually I had almost the same : \d*\s*,\s*\d*\s*,\s*\d*. Your solution is not working for 10,10,10 or 10, 10, 10 either. Mine is returning true for 10,10, : I mean mine is not correct either.

Comment: Yeah, sorry bout that.  Edited to account for that.